# Got a +1 notice when undownvoting post despite not having earned reputation

Tags: bug, downvotes, notifications, daily-reputation-limit, undo

Steps to reproduce (all on the same day):

1. Downvote an answer.
2. Be nice to everyone, get upvotes, and hit the rep cap.
3. Remove the downvote on that answer

The vote is removed from my [reputation history](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation), my rep is recalculated, leading to one of the entries to be capped by one more point - my reputation doesn't change.
Regardless, I've got a green <kbd>+1</kbd> notification on the "recent achievements" in the top bar. This shouldn't happen.

[image: undoing a downvote]
[image: receiving a notification]

Comment: If the way that the cap works is that you can't get more than +200 gross rep in a day, then if you remove a downvote, I'd imagine the rep you gain back doesn't count towards the limit, since it's removing a penalty rather than gaining rep.

Comment: Yeah, isn't the +200 cap only for upvotes and approved edits?  But it is interesting to display a +1.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo: No, penalties do count towards the limit. If I downvote 5 times (-5) and am downvoted 5 times (-10), I can gain up to 215 rep from upvotes - balancing out at +200.

Comment: I find it interesting that very high-rep users like you, still notice any little bit of rep handled by the system. That's kinda stuff I'm only halfway noticing at all ;-) ...

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238766/

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'd not assume it is about noticing rep, but "attention to detail", which is good.

Comment: @BillWoodger Yeah, right.

Comment: AFAIK there are some anomalies in the way rep cap is calculated on a momentary basis, but these are smoothed out at the end of each day. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94458/how-does-stack-overflow-handle-cancelled-upvotes-from-a-day-that-the-cap-was-hit

Comment: @JLRishe: IIRC, they went away from that approach and calculate everything instantly now, always taking the whole history into account. There should be a blog post somewhere, announcing also the removal of the `trigger recalculation` button.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo The basic rep cap rules are at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32160/what-is-the-daily-reputation-cap-and-how-can-i-hit-it, although that doesn't cover everything you guys are talking about, it's a good reference.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce. Specifically this part: `Be nice to everyone` ;)

Comment: The actual relevant MSE post is [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236420/when-will-my-reputation-update/236424#236424). Read it carefully - this is not a *simple* bug.

Comment: @MattBurland: Rep-whoring works as well. But I didn't want to suggest to that in the steps-to-reproduce :-)

Comment: Just confirmed; that's strange...

Answer (score -5):

Well, when you downvote on answers (I think you did that), you get **-1** reputation for downvoting. However, when you "undownvote", the reputation change is erased, you get **+1**.

Comment: No. I did not get any reputation (as is proper, due to the cap).

Comment: That said, it's both interesting and strange.